# QGIS: Median for Raster layer zonal statistics

Tags: qgis, raster, statistics, median

I want to know the **median value of Raster A based on the value-defined areas of raster B**. Using the Raster layer zonal statistics, I receive "only" value of sum, min, max and average.

I used already **Zonal Statistics** command, using a shapefile based on raster B, and checked for the median to be calculated. As a result however, the areas in the shapefile based on raster B are now split to thousands of different areas, making it impossible to create a median out of it.

Also, I used the **r.statistics** command, taking raster A as the base and raster B as the cover. Unfortunately, the process always crashes after a few seconds... and the log panel of **r.statistics** says "*The following layers were not correctly generated.*", whereas the Log Message Panel says "*Task complete: Exectungin r.statistics*"

Has someone an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I opened a feature request on this topic some time ago. Unfortunately, it's not as straightforward to achieve. In the end, I resolved it using an R script; I suppose it could be implemented using Pandas or Numpy, but I haven't had the opportunity to work on it yet. Certainly, one must be careful about how the data is processed because the issue is that this calculation consumes a lot of computer resources, and if you're analyzing data at a high resolution and large scale, it might run into memory errors.

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/40655